# Trying to pass the input value in the query string but failing why?

Tags: jquery

I have this code in the page.

```
<input type="text" value="Enter your video URL here..." size="30" class="video_url" />

<input type="button" value="Preview" class="preview_button" />

<div id="preview"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

    $(".preview_button").click(function(){

        var url = $('.video_url').val();

        $("#preview").load('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/templates/preview.php?url=' + url);

    });

}) (jQuery);
</script>
```

However on preview.php I can never see the url value. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use a HTTP traffic analyzer (HttpFox, Firebug) to check the URL of the HTTP request that jQuery sends.

Comment: a) `console.log(url)` to see what you're getting; b) Your php code is irrelevant and confusing: show us the same JS the browser sees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried encodeURI?

```
$("#preview").load('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/templates/preview.php?url=' + encodeURI(url));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Adding encodeURI makes it work perfect !

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another element on the same page with a class of `video_url`?  I'd use IDs since classes aren't necessarily unique.